# How do I assign the sprite layer in the function definition in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am trying to code a game called 'Scrolling Shooter' with Pygame. I am trying to draw sprites over each other in the right order. In the initialization function of each sprite class, I assign an attribute called 'layer'. According to the pygame docs, this should change the layer of the sprite in the sprite in the allSprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates() function and the sprites with a higher value of layer should be drawn on top of sprites with a lower value. Despite the parameter, if I use get_layer_of_sprite in the draw function, it just gives 0. Somebody on the r/pygame subreddit said that the attribute should be _layer instead of layer but that didn't work either.

The allSprites.draw(display) function is in my draw() funtion. The draw() function is called in each iteration of the main loop.

You can find the relevant code here:
https://github.com/CiriOfRivia/Pygame-Scrolling-Shooters/blob/master/hi

You can find the full code here:
https://github.com/CiriOfRivia/Pygame-Scrolling-Shooters/blob/master/Layering%20issue

Pygame docs:
"If the sprite you add has an attribute layer then that layer will be used. If the **kwarg contains 'layer' then the sprites passed will be added to that layer (overriding the sprite.layer attribute). If neither sprite has attribute layer nor **kwarg then the default layer is used to add the sprites."

Thanks in advance for helping me. I probably did one little thing wrong which messes up everything, which is so often the case when I'm coding.

If I add the layer to the sprites after initializing them, it seems to work fine. However, I want to be able to set the layer in the initialization function.

Expected result:
The layer of the plane is higher than the layer of the island, thus the plane should be drawn over the island.
The output should be:
Plane 3
Island 1

Actual result:
The layer of the plane is equal to the layer of the island. The drawing order is random and the island gets drawn over the plane
The output is:
Plane 0
Island 0

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have found a work-around by putting pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates.change_layer(allSprites, self, self.layer)
inside of the initialization function.
I still don't understand why it didn't work in the first place.